# How to change Accuweather widget location in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, weather-api

I'm trying to load an Accuweather widget which can change in location using a dropdown list. It works when there's no loaded location at first. But when i try to change the location, it doesn't work anymore. My guess is I should recall the Accuweather script or function (but I don't know how). Here's the [link of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egX7D.jpg) of what I've done.

And here's a part of my JS code:

```
$('#awcc1414464209059').attr('data-locationkey',selected); //change the div's data-location-key to the selected location's key
$('#awcc1414464209059').attr('class',"aw-widget-current");
$('#awcc1414464209059').attr('data-unit', "c");
$('#awcc1414464209059').attr('data-language',"en-us");
$('#awcc1414464209059').attr('data-useip', "false");
$('#awcc1414464209059').attr('data-uid',"awcc1414464209059");
getweather();

function getweather(){
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "assets/js/accuweather.js"; 
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  return false;
}
```

PS: It would be better if I can load multiple widgets at once, so that I can display all the locations for users' convenience. (I tried it already but I can't make it work)

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work out. For those who need help with the same problem, you need to reload the script file for accuweather.

```
for ($m=0; $m < sizeof($mun_name); $m++) { 
 $echo .= '<a href="" class="aw-widget-legal"></a>
 <div id="awcc1414464'.$weather_id[$m].'" data-locationkey="'.$weather_id[$m].'" class="aw-widget-current" data-unit="c" data-language="en-us" data-useip="false" data-uid="awcc1414464'.$weather_id[$m].'"></div>
 <script>getweather()</script>';
}
```

In my code, the getweather() function loads the script and adds it to the html head, thus giving me the [result in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcQgg.jpg).